# Excel insert picture based on result no VBA

Tags: excel

Is there a way without using VBA that would insert picture A if value is positive and Picture B if values is negative?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using VBA?

Comment: Probably but why over complicate things?

Comment: VBA disabled by company policy.

Answer (score 1):

Time to break out the `Camera` tool.

In Excel 2010 this can be found in `File`~`Options`~`Quick Access Toolbar`~`All Commands`.
[image]

On `Sheet2` resize your cells so the picture can be pasted into a single cell. 
[image]

- Select a cell (not the picture) that one of the pictures is in.
- Click the camera tool
- Select `Sheet1` and click on the sheet.
  This will place the picture on the sheet within a picture box. Note the cell reference to `Sheet2` in the formula bar.

[image]

Open the `Name Manager` and create a named range:
`=IF(Sheet1!$B$2<0,Sheet2!$B$3,Sheet2!$B$4)`
`Sheet1!B2` will hold the positive/negative value.  True is reference to the cell (`B3`) holding picture 1, False is reference to the cell (`B4`) holding picture 2.
I've given it the name `PictureDisplay`.

Select the picture on Sheet1 and change the formula in the formula bar from `=Sheet2!$B$3` to `=PictureDisplay`.

Change the value in `Sheet1!B2` from Positive to Negative and the picture will change.