# display chart with if function in EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement, charts

I am currently creating a reporting chart for my company and i want to make it as easy as possible to set up this reporting. 
Currently I am struggling with displaying charts in a nice way. My idea is that the user writes a 1 in say Cell A1, then a certain chart will show up at position A20, if he writes nothing it will not show.

My idea  was something like

```
if(A1=1;Chart1;"")
```

but unfortenatuly it does not work. Does anybody know a solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't want to use VBA you could use the solution I gave in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236243/excel-insert-picture-based-on-result-no-vba/45240229#45240229

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Chart is object display, not object calculate.
So I think your ideal can be doing by marco.

```
If Cells(1, 1).Value = "a 1" Then
     'Display chart in cell A20
Else
     Cells(20, 1).Value = ""
End If
```